# C# - Deserialize a nested JSON to string

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, backend

I'd like to deserialize a nested JSON object into a string to avoid having to write code to handle lots of special cases.

Json looks like this:

```
{
  "configurationType": "ConfigType",
  "description" : "some description",
  "changeJson" : {
    "newValues": [ 
      { ... }
    ],
    "oldValues": [
      { ... }
    ]
  }
}
```

The object I'm trying to deserialize into looks like this:

```
public class AddConfigurationRequest
{
    public ConfigurationChangeType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ChangeJson { get; set; }
}
```

Using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddConfigurationChange>()` fails on the `ChangeJson`. Is there a workaround or a solution to this?

The reason why I want to do this is because it's part of a config submit/approval system, which has different configuration types to take into account. The `newValues` and `oldValues` can be either an array or singular values, depending on the `ConfigurationType`. Setting `ChangeJson` to `JObject` or `dynamic` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `JToken`, and then `.toString()` when saving to the database.

```
public class AddConfigurationRequest
{
    public ConfigurationChangeType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public JToken ChangeJson { get; set; }
}
```